# Install Git on FreeBSD without admin privileges

Tags: software-installation, sudo, freebsd

Is it possible to install `git` on FreeBSD 8.0 without administrator privileges?

I do not have `pkg` (it only appeared on 9.1). Anyway, I can't use `sudo` so I can't even use `portsnap`... Or maybe it is possible? Did not found any information about that.

**Edit**

I try to install from source:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.12.0.tar.xz
tar -zxvf git-2.12.0.tar.xz && cd git-2.12.0
./configure && make
...
```

Receive a bunch of error, among them:

```
"config.mak.uname", line 490: Missing dependency operator
"config.mak.uname", line 542: warning: duplicate script for target "(,)" ignored
"config.mak.uname", line 547: Need an operator
"config.mak.uname", line 152: warning: duplicate script for target "ifeq" ignored
Error expanding embedded variable.
```

`make -v` or `--version` does not work.

vi: `g is'nt a vi command`

Comment: Could you define what "install" means to you here?

Comment: I downloaded the source with ````wget````, uncompressed, configured, then... make  got a bunch of errors.

Comment: Install... I want to be able to use git. I do not have the git command line tool installed.

Comment: ````"config.mak.uname", line 152: warning: duplicate script for target "ifeq" ignored````

Comment: You can [edit] your post to add compilation errors.

Comment: should I edit my post to describe what I tried ?

Comment: [Yes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: make -v or --version do not work. vi: ````g is'nt a vi command````?!

Comment: FreeBSD 8 had support dropped in August 2015. No more patches, and no more Ports. You really would be better to update to a [supported version](https://www.freebsd.org/security/#sup)

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD's make is different from Linux one. You'd first need GNU make (`gmake`). It can be obtained from [devel/gmake](http://www.freshports.org/devel/gmake/) port or `gmake` package.

If you don't have administrative rights you can still use ports to compile from sources and `pkg` to install binaries.

### ports

If you already have ports tree in `/usr/ports`, you can just copy `/usr/ports/devel/gmake/` into your home dir and run `make` there. You'd probably need to override some variables to put everything in your home dir.

Otherwise you can checkout whole ports tree into your home dir and compile whatever you want.

### pkg

You can use `pkg fetch git` command to download compiled git package and then unpack it into your custom prefix.

Comment: I'm on freebsd 8.0. Pkg is not there.